# AWS Lex - Cloudwatch Logs

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-lex

Have a weird case. I have configured Amazon Lex Bot (V2) and have created Twilio Channel to integrate with WhatsApp. The Bot is working all fine on WhatsApp. I have enabled Text Conversational logs and see that the logs are recorded only for one mobile number whereas logs are not recorded for any other mobile numbers. Do we need to do any more configuration to log all the users conversational logs?

Many thanks

Comment: Further observed that the logging is happening from some mobile numbers and not from some of them. Not sure what is causing this.

Comment: Are all interactions going through to the same version/alias of your bot? What is your session timeout? Is it possible that the interactions that are logged are new sessions whereas the ones that aren't are old/existing sessions?

Comment: Reegz, Thanks for your response. I see that out of 10 mobiles I have checked, 2 mobiles have issue. So, I think from business perspective we are good for now. Appreciate you replying to this.

Answer (score 0):

The logs started appearing fine now. Not sure what could be the issue. Since I am able to see the logs now, marking this as closed. Technically no changes are made, same old setup was working fine.